# Oreo failed to post notification on channel null

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications, android-8.0-oreo

i am trying to make notification push using FCM but every time when i am trying to send notification my Emulator always toasting failed to post notification on channel null,

i have trying many ways about posting notification on channel, but none of it is correct

i am using 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.0'

here is my code

```
  private void sendMyNotification(String message) {

        int NOTIFICATION_ID = 234;
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            String CHANNEL_ID = "my_channel_01";
            CharSequence name = "my_channel";
            String Description = "This is my channel";
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
            NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
            mChannel.setDescription(Description);
            mChannel.enableLights(true);
            mChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
            mChannel.enableVibration(true);
            mChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400});
            mChannel.setShowBadge(false);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
            NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle("LALALLA")
                    .setContentText(message);

            Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
            stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
            stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
            PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            builder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
            notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
        } else {
            //On click of notification it redirect to this Activity
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

            Uri soundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
            NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle("My Firebase Push notification")
                    .setContentText(message)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setSound(soundUri)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

            notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());

        }
```

my manifest.xml

```
<service android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <service android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

Answer (score 0):

i solved my problem by upgrading my 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.0' to newer version

for example , now iam using : 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'